# Outlook on-send dialog add-in breaks when browser window is resized

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in that displays a dialog box when the send button is pressed. The problem is that when it runs online and the browser window is resized, the whole js script is run again. The original dialog persists but it cannot be closed as the dialog variable is now undefined (from the script being rerun) so the .close() method cannot be used. Also since the dialog variable is redefined, communication with the dialog cannot be done and the add-in is rendered useless.

The code is something like this:

```
Office.onReady(() => {});
var dialog

function openDialog(event) {
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() function (asyncResult) {url, {height: 50, width: 50},displayInIframe: true}, 
      function(asyncResult){
              if (asyncResult.error.code == 12007)) {
                        dialog.close()    //this will not run as 'dialog' is now undefined from the script rerun
                        event.completed({allowEvent: false})
                       }
                  } else {
                        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, doSomething);}
      }
```

Why does the browser rerun the script when the window is resized and what can be done to prevent this problem?

The manifest is hosted here: hamish-atkins-sb.github.io/Email-domain-checker/manifest.xml

All of the code can be seen here: github.com/Hamish-Atkins-SB/Email-domain-checker

Comment: Can you clarify the platform that this issue is showing up for? Is it for Outlook Win32 or Outlook on the Web? When you say "when it runs online and the browser window is resized" do you mean this for the opened dialog or the browser window where Outlook is running on?

Comment: The problem is on Outlook on the Web and it is for the browser window where Outlook is running (not the dialog).

Comment: My code is here: https://github.com/Hamish-Atkins-SB/Email-domain-checker and can be sideloaded from here: https://hamish-atkins-sb.github.io/Email-domain-checker/manifest.xml

Comment: The reloading of the Javascript only happens when the window width is being increased (not decreased) and it happens at around these points: 490px 650px, 1025px, 1400px, 1920px (Outlook window width not the dialog window width). This makes me think that Microsoft has some sort of dynamic styling or js that reloads the add-in for different screen sizes on the web.

Comment: The dialog is being opened as an iframe. When the dialog is instead opened using: `displayInIframe: false` (as a seperate pop-up window) a second dialog opens when the screen is resized.

Comment: It happends on Chrome, FIrefox and Edge. It is almost like the page withdraws the on-send event when it is resized.

Comment: If the add-in is hosted online, could you please share the manifest file so that we could reproduce it?

Comment: The manifest can be found here: hamish-atkins-sb.github.io/Email-domain-checker/manifest.xml and all of the code can be seen here: github.com/Hamish-Atkins-SB/Email-domain-checker

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding on send pop-up. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point 

Internal tracking id: Office: 2453181